# Skip Jenkins pipeline stage on local dev environment condition

Tags: jenkins, groovy, pylint

I have a Jenkins pipeline script that has a step which executes 2 linters(PyLint and Flake8) triggered by a pull request like this.

```
pipeline {
        agent any
        stages {
            stage('PR Lint') {
                when { branch "PR-*" }
                steps {
                    parallel(
                        flake8: {
                            sh "mkdir flake8"
                            sh "git diff -U0 | tox -r -e flake8 -- --diff - --exit-zero --tee --output-file=flake8/flake8.txt"
                            archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: '**/flake8/*.txt'
                            step([
                            $class: 'ViolationsToGitHubRecorder',
                            config: violation_to_github_config
                            ])
                        },
                        pylint: {
                            script{
                               if( readFile('tox.ini').contains('[testenv:pylint]')){
                                    sh "mkdir pylint"
                                    sh "tox -e pylint -- --errors-only --output-format=parseable > pylint/pylint.txt || true"
                                    archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: '**/pylint/*.txt'
                                    step([
                                    $class: 'ViolationsToGitHubRecorder',
                                    config: violation_to_github_config
                                    ])
                               }
                            }
                    })
```

I want to give developers the option to skip the execution of PyLint depending on any local configuration. As you can see I currently have a line `if(readFile('tox.ini').contains('[testenv:pylint]'))` but this change in the config would get pushed to the repository on merge and I don't want that.

Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add another file, which would be on `.gitignore`, so it won't be checked in. Then you can simply extend your existing `if` to check if the file exists, or extend your `when` directive. E.g.:

```
when {
    anyOf {
        branch "PR-*"
        expression { !fileExists("local") } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Still a bit confused. If it's not checked in(in `.gitignore`). How would Jenkins know of it's existence? Would this allow devs to change the preference on each PR whether to run PyLint or not ?

Comment: @shanwar OK, so you want `PyLint` to be executed locally, but not on Jenkins? That is still not clear to me.

Comment: On Jenkins, but I want the devs to have the choice to run it there.